# error handling when using splitter\aggregator in spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have following IntegrationFlow:

```
...
.split()
...
multiple transformations here
...
split()
...
multiple transformations here
...
.aggregate()
.aggregate()
```

How can I guaranty that the two aggregators will behave as usual (i.e. make those aggregators believe that the upstream processing has been successful for all "split-messages") even if an exception is thrown in one of the intermediary message transformations ?
Note: as I have several intermediary transformations, I can't afford to add a try/catch to each and every of those transformations...one potential idea would be, maybe, to wrap each of my "...multiple transformations here..." into something like `.gateway(subflow,c -> c.advice(myAdvice))` ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your expertise.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On of the option is to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, but as you noticed then you have to add into every single step between `split` and `aggregate`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice.

Another option as you pointed out would be a `gateway()` for those processing steps with a single error handler. And yes: same `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` could be used in the mentioned `advice()` this way any exception thrown from a `GatewayMessageHandler` (essentially `subflow`) would be handled by only one `try..catch`.

You would need to ensure to copy a failed message headers to fulfill an aggregator expectations for correlation.

Another way is to use an `errorChannel()` on that `GatewayEndpointSpec` for a `try..catch` logic, but I guess it would be similar to what we can do with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

Comment: as usual, thanks a lot for taking time to answer questions from grassroots users like me!